Why was i rejected before taking the assessment
I was invited for a assessment but due to technical issues I couldn't access the link they said i would hear from them shortly.
But got rejected before taking the assessment

I'm sorry, but it is very difficult to answer this question because we have no insight into this company. Please fix your technical issue.

We cannot know the mind of your interviewers - but the most likely:

they already found and picked a suitable candidate in the meantime and thus it makes no sense for them to go ahead with other candidates
enough candidates passed the assessment stage of the application process for them to be confident one of them will be a good enough fit, such that they do not need to spend any time with additional candidates that are not as far in the process and would need individual arrangements


Also, the interviewers may be personally very strict.
